# Is this differential equation for zeta on the critical line? One can compute it from its derivative and simpler functions

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function

Looks like on the critical line one can compute
$\zeta(1/2+it)$ from $\zeta^{'}(1/2+it)$ and simpler functions.

Let

$$
\begin{aligned}
f(t)= & 2\, \left( {\frac { \left(  \left| \zeta^{'}  \left( 1/2+it \right) 
 \right|  \right) ^{2}\Gamma  \left( 1/4-1/2\,it \right) }{\zeta^{'} 
 \left( 1/2+it \right) }}+\Gamma  \left( 1/4+1/2\,it \right) \zeta^{'} 
 \left( 1/2+it \right) {\pi }^{-it} \right) \\
 & \left( \Gamma  \left( 1
/4+1/2\,it \right)  \right) ^{-1} \left( {\pi }^{-it} \right) ^{-1}
 \left( 2\,\ln  \left( \pi  \right) -\psi \left( 1/4+1/2\,it \right) -
\psi \left( 1/4-1/2\,it \right)  \right) ^{-1}
\end{aligned}
$$

For real $t$ we have $\zeta(1/2+it)=f(t)$, except possibly at zeros
of $\zeta^{'}(1/2+it)$.

So we can compute $\zeta(1/2+it)$ given $\zeta^{'}(1/2+it)$
and computing simpler functions like the digamma $\psi$.

> Q1 Is this really a differential equation for zeta on the critical
>   line?
>
> Q2 In case of positive answer to Q1, what is its classification?

Plot:
[image]
Sage code in machine readable form:

```
  def f(t):
    """
    """
    import mpmath
    from mpmath import gamma,zeta,log,psi
    J=mpmath.j
    Pi=mpmath.pi
    t=mpmath.mpc(t)
    return 2*( ( mpmath.fabs(zeta(1/2+J*t,derivative=1))**2/zeta(1/2+J*t,derivative=1) )*gamma(1/4-J*t/2)+gamma(1/4+J*t/2)*zeta(1/2+J*t,derivative=1)*Pi**(-J*t))/(gamma(1/4+J*t/2)*Pi**(-J*t)*(2*log(Pi)-psi(0,1/4+J*t/2)-psi(0,1/4-J*t/2 ) )) # should equal zeta(1/2+J*t) for real $t$
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The zeta function can be written $\zeta(1/2+it)=Z(t)e^{-i\vartheta(t)}$ where 
$Z(t)$ are real analytic and $\vartheta(t)$ is a simple function related to 
$\Gamma(s)$. The relation between $\zeta(1/2+it)$ and $\zeta'(1/2+it)$ can be written
in a simpler form
$$-2\vartheta'(t)\zeta(1/2+it)=\zeta'(1/2+it)+e^{-2i\vartheta(t)}\zeta'(1/2-it)$$
in which you may change $\zeta'(1/2-it)=|\zeta'(1/2+it)|^2/\zeta'(1/2+it)$. 
This is proved in page 222 of  the paper ``[On the exact location of the non-trivial
zeros of Riemann's zeta function](https://eudml.org/doc/279194)'', Acta Arithm. 163 (2004) 215--245.

The proof do not depend on the nature of $Z(t)$. So this ``differential equation''
is satisfied by $f(1/2+it) =e^{-i\vartheta(t)} u(t)$ with $u$ any even real analytic function.
Therefore it has no information about the zeros of zeta.

Comment: Thank you the given $f(t)$ depends on the right $Z(t)$, so it computes zeta zeros.

Comment: More generally, zeta function universality basically ensures that the only differential equations obeyed by zeta are those coming from meromorphicity and the functional equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeta_function_universality